# Mongoose not adding virtual property in the response object using virtual populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So in my project i have two different models . Tour Model and Review Model. Review Model has parent reference of tour id. I want to add virtual populate on tour model so that I can get all reviews related to the tour. Basically doing it other way round.
So what I am expecting here is that whenever I hit a route on getTour I should see a property called "reviews" added to the response object but there is actually isn't. Please tell me is there anything I'm missing here.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify');
const User = require('./userModel');
const Review = require('./reviewModel');
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
      unique: true,
      maxlength: [40, 'A tour namme must have less or equal 40 characters'],
      minlength: [10, 'A tour namme must have greater or equal 10 characters'],
    },
    slug: String,
    duration: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a duration'],
    },

    maxGroupSize: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a GroupSize'],
    },
    difficulty: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have difficulty'],
    },

    ratingsQuantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    ratingsAverage: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4.5,
      min: [1, 'Rating must be above 1.0'],
      max: [5, 'Rating must be below 5.0'],
    },

    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a price '],
    },
    priceDiscount: {
      type: Number,
      validate: {
        validator: function (val) {
          return val < this.price;
        },
        message: 'Discount must be lower than the price',
      },
    },

    summary: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have summary'],
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    imageCover: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A tour must have a cover image'],
    },
    images: [String],
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
    },
    startDates: [Date],
    secretTour: {
      type: Boolean,
      dafault: false,
    },
    startLocation: {
      //Geo json
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
        enum: ['Point'],
      },
      coordinates: [Number],
      address: String,
      description: String,
    },
    locations: [
      {
        type: {
          type: String,
          default: 'Point',
          enum: ['Point'],
        },
        coordinates: [Number],
        address: String,
        description: String,
        day: Number,
      },
    ],
    guides: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

tourSchema.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Review', //name of model
  foreignField: 'tour', //foreign property in review model
  localField: '_id',
});

const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);

module.exports = Tour;
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const slugify = require('slugify');

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    review: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      min: 1,
      max: 5,
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Review must belong to a user'],
    },
    tour: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Tour',
      required: [true, 'Review must belong to a tour'],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

reviewSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
  this.populate({
    path: 'user',
    select: 'name',
  }).populate({
    path: 'tour',
    select: 'name',
  });
  next();
});

const Review = mongoose.model('Review', reviewSchema);
module.exports = Review;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to populate **reviews** field. so after doing virtual property write this code below it in file contains tourSchema.

If you want to find single tour

```
tourSchema.pre('findOne', function (next) {
  this.populate('reviews');
  next();
});
```